# Symmetric difference operation in Transact-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have always known about the `UNION` operator in SQL, but only recently discovered that there were other set operators, `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT`. I haven't been able to find an operator that does the fourth big set operator, the symmetric difference (e.g. the opposite of `INTERSECT`.)

It looks like I can get the desired output by using something like

```
SELECT Field FROM A UNION SELECT Field FROM B 
EXCEPT
SELECT Field FROM A INTERSECT SELECT Field FROM B
```

(assuming I got the precedence right), or by doing an anti-full-join:

```
SELECT A.Field, B.Field
FROM A
FULL JOIN B ON B.Id = A.Id
WHERE B.Id IS NULL OR A.Id IS NULL
```

But both of those look like rather intensive queries, especially compared to the other three basic set operations. Is there a symmetric difference operation in SQL and I just can't find it in the documentation? Or is there a "canonical" way to implement it in T-SQL?

Comment: `(a EXCEPT b) UNION ALL (b EXCEPT a);` might be more efficient.

Comment: @ypercube that does 3 joins or join-like operations. I cannot think of any reason this might be more efficient than a full join.

Comment: @usr it's actually 2 join-like operations, not 3. Union All is much less costly operation. I agree that `FULL JOIN` may be more efficient. Testing can reveal which is best. And of course, if more/different columns from each table are needed, my solution is not easily expandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All set operators are translated to joins or join-like operators. You can witness that in the query plan.

For that reason the full outer join that you have there is the most efficient you can do. Disregarding, of course, the hopefully rare situation in which the optimizer picks a bad plan and a rewrite happens to perform better by luck. This can always happen.

Comment: That makes sense, however, the reason I like to use the set operators is because they don't create "extra columns"... I can do things like `SELECT Id FROM A WHERE <stuff> EXCEPT Select Id FROM A WHERE <other stuff>` and get a single list of `Id`. I can't figure out how to do that with a full join... do I just need to deal with having two sets of `Id` columns and union them back together myself?

Comment: You can say `ISNULL(a.Col, b.Col) AS Col`. Wrap that in a derived table or CTE and you can use the "folded" result set for further operation on it. (Btw, I agree the symmetric difference operator should exist.)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield On the other hand, what about when you *want* other columns that aren't being used in the compare/distinct? You can do that with a join but not with intersect/except. So I could see in some cases that variation actually ending up becoming much more complex in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a pretty good solution.  It uses a union all between two selects with Not Exists sub-queries.  Better than combining Union and Except because you can include fields that don't match in the projection.

```
SELECT  'A' TableName, FileType FROM KFX_Inventory I 
    WHERE Not Exists (Select Top 1 1 from KFX_FileType FT WHERE FT.FileType = I.FileType)
UNION ALL
SELECT  'B', FileType FROM KFX_FILEType FT 
    WHERE Not Exists (Select Top 1 1 from KFX_Inventory I WHERE FT.FileType = I.FileType)
```